# iOS Keeping a SearchBar in palce with SWIFT

Tags: swift, ios8, uisearchbar

I am programming with Swift for iOS 8.
I would like to have a SearchBar on top of a Table that looks like and behave exactly like the one in Contacts App in the iPhone.

So far I have a UIViewControl embedded in a NavigationController, added an UISearchBar and an UITabelView to the UIViewControl. The Table is populated with data and searching is working. Problem: when I dismiss the keyboard, the Cancel Button is greyed out.

When I add the SearchBar with code and put it in self.tableView.tableHeaderView,
Keyboard and Cancel buttons works as expected but the SearchBar stays not in place when scrolling the tableView.

None of the many tutorials and advices I found solved the problem.

Any advices or tips?

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: "Cancel buttons works as expected but the SearchBar stays not in place when scrolling the tableView." - this tells me you haven't got proper constraints in place for your search bar. And you're possibly nesting the search bar within the tableView. You want them on the same level of the view hiearchy